# we are not getting Symantec in the trusted key store default

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

verify that the certificate is signed by the trusted CA.I tried to getlist of Trusted X509Certificate by using the method of getAcceptedIssuers().

```
X509Certificate[] cert2= getAcceptedIssuers();
```

In that list Common Name(Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3,) it is not available. 
How can i get this value in default Trust manager?

```
 @Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    if (!false) {
        X509Certificate cert=chain[0];
        Log.d("bucky validate 0",chain[0].getIssuerDN().getName());
        boolean found = false;
        try {
            String dns= String.valueOf(cert.getIssuerDN());
            Log.d("bucky validate",dns);
            X509Certificate[] cert2= getAcceptedIssuers();
            int length=cert2.length;
            for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
               String dnName= String.valueOf(cert2[i].getIssuerDN());
                Log.d("bucky validate2",dnName);
            }
            cert.checkValidity(new Date());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}


@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
{
    return defaultTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers() ;
}



public ApplicationTrustManager() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init((KeyStore) null);
    defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got the answer.Its minor mistake.

```
     @Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException
```

Last value of the chain array ,i got the trusted certificate name.